# Erro - Ícone Font-Awesome

Tags: font-awesome

Preciso Adicionar um ícone em um menu, o ícone que quero utilizar é o:

> fa fa-file-pdf-o (PDF)

Da classe:

> font-awesome.min.css

Só que existe um problema quando adiciono o mesmo. Ele aparece da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código HTML que cria esse item de menu está abaixo:

```
<div class="caixa" title="Gerar PDF" id="pdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pdf">
        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
        <br>
        <h4>PDF</h4>
</div>
```

E o código CSS dessas tag está a seguir:

```
.caixa{ 
        background-color: white;
        display: inline-table;  /*o inline-block deixa na mesma linha horizontal*/ 
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 5%;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 5%;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        float: right;
}
.fa:before{
        font-family: FontAwesome !important;
}
.caixa h4{
        font-family: century gothic;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        font-size: 90%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
}
```

O **erro** reportado pelo navegador é este:

> **Failed to load resource:** the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) fontawesome-webfont.ttf
>
> **Failed to load resource:** the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) fontawesome-webfont.woff

A minha página php que solicita o arquivo css:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo que é requisitado está dentro da *pasta css*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a forma como ele é importado dentro do código...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu estava dando uma olhada aqui e conseguir achar que o problema pelo qual estava tendo, de acordo com o erro que o navegador informava é que ele solicitava dois arquivos que se encontravam dentro da pasta *fonts*, que na verdade nem existia, mas ele especificava isso no caminho, então lembrei que quando baixei havia essa pasta com os dois arquivos que estavam sendo solicitados pelo navegador, então baixei novamente o arquivo e adicionei a pasta com os dois arquivos e deu certo!

Então no caso quando for importado o arquivo font-awesome.min.css deve ser também colocado a pasta fonts, se no caso for utilizar os ícones da classe.

Answer (score 1):

Tente alterar a forma de importação para:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/font-awesome.css">
```

Comment: relatorio.php:1 GET http://localhost/Sistema%20-%20Controle%20Geral%20de%20Alunos/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0 
relatorio.php:1 GET http://localhost/Sistema%20-%20Controle%20Geral%20de%20Alunos/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0 404 (Not Found) Apresentou esses erros!